# NSFileHandle writeData: exception handling

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, nsfilehandle

This could be rather broad problem but I could not find any online resource addressing or explaining this matter.

The question is after creating `NSFileHandle *writer = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForWritingAtPath:"path"]` and when you use `[writer writedata:"NSData"]` there are sine possible exception that could fire according to the apple doc.

> "This method raises an exception if the file descriptor is closed or is
>   not valid, if the receiver represents an unconnected pipe or socket
>   endpoint, if no free space is left on the file system, or if any other
>   writing error occurs." - APPLE DOC

All I want to know is is there any way we can handle or validate these issues without using any try catch or checking for each error in a condition check before write. Any possible way we can use `NSError` to handle this ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would say "No".  If you did manage to find a test that covered all possible failures before writing, then there is nothing to say that the write operation might fail after this initial test (think about writing to a filesystem with 1KB free and you want to write 4KB).

Therefore wrapping your calls to these methods inside a `@try/@catch` block would seem to me to be the best approach.  These wrappers could then return an `NSError **` if you want details of the failure (which you most certainly should want).

```
- (BOOL)writeData:(NSData *)data
     toFileHandle:(NSFileHandle *)fileHandler
            error:(NSError **)error
{
    @try
    {
        [fileHandler writeData:data];
    }
    @catch (NSException *e)
    {
        if (error != NULL)
        {
            NSDictionary *userInfo = @{ 
                NSLocalizedDescriptionKey : @"Failed to write data",
                // Other stuff?
            };
            *error = [NSError errorWithDomain:@"MyStuff" code:123 userInfo:userInfo];
        }
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

You will certainly want to get the reason for the failure into the `NSError`, but it's not immediately obvious to me how to go about doing this.