# Catch Objective-C exception in Swift

Tags: swift, exception, swift2, nsexception

I am trying to set the value of an `@objc` object in my Swift code using `obj.setValue(value, forKey: key)`.

It works fine when the object has the property being set. But if it doesn't, my app crashes hard with an uncaught `NSException` ("class is not key value coding-compliant…").

How can I catch and absorb this exception like I can in Objective-C so as to not crash my app? I tried wrapping it in a Swift try-catch, but it complains that none of the instructions throws and does nothing.

Comment: Do you really need KVC? Objects in dictionaries are supposed to be set with `setObject:forKey:` or key subscripting especially in Swift.

Comment: Yes, I'm writing an XML parser and need to be able to set arbitrary properties on objects by their names.

Comment: Then rather than catch an exception check if the key exists.

Comment: That would totally work. I didn't think there was a way to do that though!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Catching NSException in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32758811/catching-nsexception-in-swift)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35003095/2066810):

```
//
//  ExceptionCatcher.h
//

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>    

NS_INLINE NSException * _Nullable tryBlock(void(^_Nonnull tryBlock)(void)) {
    @try {
        tryBlock();
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception) {
        return exception;
    }
    return nil;
}
```

Comment: That did the trick! Not pretty, but I'm glad it's at least possible!

Answer (score 15):

Swift 5 version with utility error type:

```c
NS_INLINE NSException * _Nullable ExecuteWithObjCExceptionHandling(void(NS_NOESCAPE^_Nonnull tryBlock)(void)) {
    @try {
        tryBlock();
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception) {
        return exception;
    }
    return nil;
}
```

```swift
public struct NSExceptionError: Swift.Error {

   public let exception: NSException

   public init(exception: NSException) {
      self.exception = exception
   }
}

public struct ObjC {

   public static func perform(workItem: () -> Void) throws {
      let exception = ExecuteWithObjCExceptionHandling {
         workItem()
      }
      if let exception = exception {
         throw NSExceptionError(exception: exception)
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 13):

Not the answer I was hoping for, unfortunately:

> Although Swift error handling resembles exception handling in Objective-C, it is entirely separate functionality. If an Objective-C method throws an exception during runtime, Swift triggers a runtime error. There is no way to recover from Objective-C exceptions directly in Swift. Any exception handling behavior must be implemented in Objective-C code used by Swift.
>
> Excerpt From: Apple Inc. “Using Swift with Cocoa and Objective-C (Swift 2.1).” iBooks. https://itun.es/ca/1u3-0.l

My next plan of attack is to add an Objective-C function I can call out to that will wrap the attempt in `@try`/`@catch`. This really sucks, Apple.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to call out the answer given in this question:

[Catching NSException in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32758811/catching-nsexception-in-swift)

as you can still use the Swift do/catch with the call in a natural fashion, the next best thing to Swift actually catching ObjC exceptions as it should.