# Unable to catch `RealmFileException: Realm file decryption failed` exception

Tags: swift, realm

I'm relying on an encrypted realm to store certain data in an app written in Swift. Sometimes I face a situation where I delete a given realm and create a new one to ensure that no data will persist between certain states.

I keep track of encryption keys myself, so there is a risk that I unintentionally attempt to decrypt a realm with a wrong encryption key, which raises the following exception:

> libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type realm::RealmFileException: Unable to open a realm at path '/path/to/private.realm': Realm file decryption failed.

Since this means that I have lost the original encryption key, essentially leaving this particular realm useless, I'd like to be able to delete the realm file and start over instead of crashing.

I create the realm as suggested by the docs:

```
do {
  var configuration = Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration
  configuration.encryptionKey = ...
  try Realm(configuration: configuration)
}
catch let error {

}
```

I've tried  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35119531/catch-objective-c-exception-in-swift) and similar approaches to catch the `NSException` and return it to be handled by Swift code, but there doesn't seem to be an straight forward way to achieve this. Is it impossible, or am I approaching this incorrectly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out the problem was caused by a bug in Realm, where `deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded = true` when using encryption, caused the exception to be thrown, but impossible to catch.

From my (very helpful) correspondence with kishikawa katsumi:

> The problem that unable to catch error is due to `deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded` is true. It changes code flow unintentionally. It seems Realm's bug. We will fix soon.

For now, the only thing to do in my case is to set `deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded = false` and handle this case manually. I have filed [this issue](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/3961) to Realm.

**Update**: The issue should be resolved with [this commit](https://github.com/realm/realm-object-store/commit/1f2090dd2faaa34b587d04ddcf3ca76efc8acdb2).

Answer (score 4):

Your code should work. If the encryption key is wrong, entered the catch block. Then you can delete existing file and re-create Realm. Like the following:

```
var configuration = Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration
configuration.encryptionKey = getKey()
do {
    let realm = try Realm(configuration: configuration)
    ...
}
catch {
    try! NSFileManager().removeItemAtURL(configuration.fileURL!)
    let realm = try! Realm(configuration: configuration)
    ...
}
```

If you cannot catch the wrong encryption error, it might be using old Realm.framework. Please update the latest version of Realm.

Comment: Thanks for replying kishikawa. I just verified that we are using Realm 1.0.2 and Realm Swift 1.0.2, which are the newest version according to your docs. The exact code I use to create the realm can be viewed [here](https://gist.github.com/kaspermunck/9b1dcbf07773b22e109eefd552200e00) (more or less copied from the docs).

Comment: @Muncken I tested your gist code, and confirmed to enter catch clause. If the problem is reproducible, can you please send the project to help@realm.io to investigate? I worked at Realm.

Comment: I have isolated the code in scope in a separate project and reproduced the problem. I will forward that to you. Leaving this thread open for now.